# Enable respective inputbox on uncheck of checkbox in angular

Tags: angular

I want to enable inputbox  on unchecked of checkbox. The checkbox will be checked by default. I have Tried the code. The code link is given below
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j6jewe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App.component.html

```
<div>
      <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f.valid, names)" novalidate>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Initial</th>
          <th>Remark</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let name of names">
          <td><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="name.checked" [checked]="true" [name]="name.id + '_checkbox'"></td>
          <td>{{name.id}}</td>
          <td>{{name.name}}</td>
          <td>{{name.Initial}}</td>
          <td><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name.remark" [disabled]="name.checked"  [name]="name.id+ '_remark'"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div>
          <div>Form details:-</div>
          <pre *ngIf="f.submitted">submitted value: <br>{{names | json}}</pre>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name.remark" [name]="name.id"
    [attr.disabled]="name.checked ? 'disabled' : null">
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sutilk?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1):

**Issue:** `name` attribute of checkbox and input box was same, so that both get disabled.

**Solution:** Differentiate `name` attribute of form components. For  setting default value, `checked` attribute is added in `names` property initialization in `app.component.ts`.

**StackBlitz solution:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tfrang?file=src/app/app.component.html